# Flink data type does not match when add time attributes by table source

Tags: events, time, apache-flink, flink-sql

I tried to add a table source with event time attribute according to [flink doc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/table/streaming/time_attributes.html#using-a-tablesource-1). My codes like:

```
class SISSourceTable
    extends StreamTableSource[Row]
    with DefinedRowtimeAttributes
    with FlinkCal
    with FlinkTypeTags {
  private[this] val profileProp = ConfigurationManager.loadBusinessProperty
  val topic: String = ...
  val schemas = Seq(
    (TsCol, SQLTimestamp),
    (DCol, StringTag),
    (CCol, StringTag),
    (RCol, StringTag)
  )

  override def getProducedDataType: DataType = DataTypes.ROW(extractFields(schemas): _*)

  override def getTableSchema: TableSchema =
    new TableSchema.Builder()
      .fields(extractFieldNames(schemas), extractFieldDataTypes(schemas))
      .build()

  override def getRowtimeAttributeDescriptors: util.List[RowtimeAttributeDescriptor] =
    Collections.singletonList(
      new RowtimeAttributeDescriptor(
        TsCol,
        new ExistingField(TsCol),
        new AscendingTimestamps
      )
    )

  override def getDataStream(execEnv: StreamExecutionEnvironment): DataStream[Row] = {
    val windowTime: Int = profileProp.getProperty("xxx", "300").toInt
    val source = prepareSource(topic)
    val colsToCheck = List(RCol, CCol, DCol)

    execEnv
      .addSource(source)
      .map(new MapFunction[String, Map[String, String]]() {
        override def map(value: String): Map[String, String] = ...
      })
      .map(new MapFunction[Map[String, String], Row]() {
        override def map(value: Map[String, String]): Row = {
          Row.of(new Timestamp(value(TsCol).toLong * 1000), value(DCol), value(CCol), value(RCol))
        }
      })
      .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor[Row](Time.seconds(windowTime)) {
        override def extractTimestamp(element: Row): Long = element.getField(0).asInstanceOf[Timestamp].getTime
      })
  }
}
```

The `source` I get in `getDataStream` method is a Kafka string source. And there's a TsCol which I extracted from each kafka record. I want to use the TsCol as event time. However the TsCol is a 10 digits timestamp with string data type, so I need to transform it to 13 digits Long data type. When I tried to use 13 digits Long data as rowtime, I got exception said rowtime can only be extract from a SQL_TIMESTAMP column. So I tranformed the ts col to a java.sql.Timestamp in the end. When I registered above Source Table and run the flink. I got following exception:

```
org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: TableSource of type com.mob.mobeye.flink.table.source.StayInStoreSourceTable returned a DataStream of data type ROW<`t` TIMESTAMP(3), `mac` STRING, `c` STRING, `r` STRING> that does not match with the data type ROW<`t` TIMESTAMP(3), `mac` STRING, `c` STRING, `r` STRING> declared by the TableSource.getProducedDataType() method. Please validate the implementation of the TableSource.
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecTableSourceScan.translateToPlanInternal(StreamExecTableSourceScan.scala:113)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecTableSourceScan.translateToPlanInternal(StreamExecTableSourceScan.scala:55)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.ExecNode.translateToPlan(ExecNode.scala:54)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.ExecNode.translateToPlan$(ExecNode.scala:52)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecTableSourceScan.translateToPlan(StreamExecTableSourceScan.scala:55)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecCalc.translateToPlanInternal(StreamExecCalc.scala:86)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecCalc.translateToPlanInternal(StreamExecCalc.scala:46)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.ExecNode.translateToPlan(ExecNode.scala:54)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.ExecNode.translateToPlan$(ExecNode.scala:52)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecCalc.translateToPlan(StreamExecCalc.scala:46)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecExchange.translateToPlanInternal(StreamExecExchange.scala:84)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecExchange.translateToPlanInternal(StreamExecExchange.scala:44)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.ExecNode.translateToPlan(ExecNode.scala:54)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.ExecNode.translateToPlan$(ExecNode.scala:52)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecExchange.translateToPlan(StreamExecExchange.scala:44)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecGroupWindowAggregate.translateToPlanInternal(StreamExecGroupWindowAggregate.scala:140)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecGroupWindowAggregate.translateToPlanInternal(StreamExecGroupWindowAggregate.scala:55)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.ExecNode.translateToPlan(ExecNode.scala:54)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.ExecNode.translateToPlan$(ExecNode.scala:52)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecGroupWindowAggregate.translateToPlan(StreamExecGroupWindowAggregate.scala:55)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecCalc.translateToPlanInternal(StreamExecCalc.scala:86)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecCalc.translateToPlanInternal(StreamExecCalc.scala:46)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.ExecNode.translateToPlan(ExecNode.scala:54)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.ExecNode.translateToPlan$(ExecNode.scala:52)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecCalc.translateToPlan(StreamExecCalc.scala:46)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecLookupJoin.translateToPlanInternal(StreamExecLookupJoin.scala:97)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecLookupJoin.translateToPlanInternal(StreamExecLookupJoin.scala:40)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.ExecNode.translateToPlan(ExecNode.scala:54)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.ExecNode.translateToPlan$(ExecNode.scala:52)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecLookupJoin.translateToPlan(StreamExecLookupJoin.scala:40)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecCalc.translateToPlanInternal(StreamExecCalc.scala:86)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecCalc.translateToPlanInternal(StreamExecCalc.scala:46)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.ExecNode.translateToPlan(ExecNode.scala:54)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.ExecNode.translateToPlan$(ExecNode.scala:52)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecCalc.translateToPlan(StreamExecCalc.scala:46)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecLookupJoin.translateToPlanInternal(StreamExecLookupJoin.scala:97)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecLookupJoin.translateToPlanInternal(StreamExecLookupJoin.scala:40)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.ExecNode.translateToPlan(ExecNode.scala:54)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.ExecNode.translateToPlan$(ExecNode.scala:52)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecLookupJoin.translateToPlan(StreamExecLookupJoin.scala:40)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecCalc.translateToPlanInternal(StreamExecCalc.scala:86)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecCalc.translateToPlanInternal(StreamExecCalc.scala:46)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.ExecNode.translateToPlan(ExecNode.scala:54)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.ExecNode.translateToPlan$(ExecNode.scala:52)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecCalc.translateToPlan(StreamExecCalc.scala:46)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecSink.translateToTransformation(StreamExecSink.scala:185)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecSink.translateToPlanInternal(StreamExecSink.scala:133)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecSink.translateToPlanInternal(StreamExecSink.scala:50)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.ExecNode.translateToPlan(ExecNode.scala:54)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.ExecNode.translateToPlan$(ExecNode.scala:52)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.physical.stream.StreamExecSink.translateToPlan(StreamExecSink.scala:50)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.StreamPlanner.$anonfun$translateToPlan$1(StreamPlanner.scala:61)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:233)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:937)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:937)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1425)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:70)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:69)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:226)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.StreamPlanner.translateToPlan(StreamPlanner.scala:60)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerBase.translate(PlannerBase.scala:149)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.translate(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:439)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.insertInto(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:327)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableImpl.insertInto(TableImpl.java:411)
```

I'm so confused that why the

ROW<`t` TIMESTAMP(3), `mac` STRING, `c` STRING, `r` STRING>

does not match with the data type

ROW<`t` TIMESTAMP(3), `mac` STRING, `c` STRING, `r` STRING>

I got similar error in another place where I replaced TIMESTAMP as Long and it worked. But here, I need column t to be extracted as rowtime, so it has to be of type TIMESTAMP(3). I greatly appreciate that someone can help with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What flink version are you using? If I am not mistaken you are using a version <1.9.2. Is that correct?

If it is so the exception message is not very helpful as it has a bug that was fixed in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-15726. Before that actually the same type was printed twice.

There are a couple of problems with your implementation. The type mismatch is most probably because you produce a `GenericTypeInformation` returned by the `map` operator in

```
      .map(new MapFunction[Map[String, String], Row]() {
        override def map(value: Map[String, String]): Row = {
          Row.of(new Timestamp(value(TsCol).toLong * 1000), value(DCol), value(CCol), value(RCol))
        }
      })
```

Try changing it to

```
      .map(new MapFunction[Map[String, String], Row]() {
        override def map(value: Map[String, String]): Row = {
          Row.of(new Timestamp(value(TsCol).toLong * 1000), value(DCol), value(CCol), value(RCol))
        }
      }).returns(Types.ROW(Types.SQL_TIMESTAMP, Types.STRING, Types.STRING, Types.STRING))
```

Secondly you don't need to assign the timestamps and watermarks within the TableSource. They will be assigned automatically based on the information provided through `DefinedRowtimeAttributes`.